# Trying to solve an equation with Sympy, TypeError: cannot create mpf from x

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy, symbolic-math, quantitative-finance

I'm attempting to solve the equation shown below. For that I have done the following:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, Sum, nsolve
import math 
#this variables are for testing purposes
cr_user = 0.25 
amount_of_days = [0.108219, 0.6082191781]
md_user = 0.6082191781
price_user = 98.37

x, i= symbols("x i")
if len(amount_of_days)% 2 == 0:
    lhs = Sum(cr_user*(math.e**(-x*(md_user-i))), (i, 0.5, 0.5*len(amount_of_days))).doit()
    rhs = Sum(-cr_user*(math.e**(-x*(md_user-i))) - (cr_user+100)*math.e**(-x*md_user) + price_user, (i, 1, 0.5*(len(amount_of_days)-1))).doit()
    print(nsolve(Eq(lhs, rhs),x))
else: 
    lhs = Sum(cr_user*(math.e**(-x*(md_user-i))), (i, 0.5,  0.5*(len(amount_of_days)-1))).doit()
    rhs = Sum(-cr_user*(math.e**(-x*(md_user-i))) - (cr_user+100)*math.e**(-x*md_user) + price_user, (i, 1, 0.5*len(amount_of_days))).doit()
    print(nsolve(Eq(lhs, rhs),x))
```

I attempt to solve for x, I always get the following error:

raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))

TypeError: cannot create mpf from x (for line 23)

[Basically the picture summarizes the code. The only difference is that I have 2 cases in the code, when len of the list is even and that when is odd. I attempt to solve for x.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J0Z9.png)

Comment: Could be 0.0480416484284691 a solution?

Comment: What would be the Python code which will calculate lhs and rhs?

Comment: @Claudio lhs and rhs are supposed to be calculated by Sum(....). The answer I'm expecting is around 0.03602 so yes!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are trying to solve the equation:
`cr_user*(e**(-x*(md_user-i))) = -cr_user*(e**(-x*(md_user-i))) - (cr_user+100)*e**(-x*md_user) + price_user`

Which is equivalent to:
`e**(-x*(md_user-i)) = (cr_user+100)*e**(-x*md_user) - price_user`

Which is equivalent to:
`e**(-x*md_user) = (cr_user+100)*e**(-x*md_user) - price_user`

Which is equivalent to:
`1 = (cr_user+100) - price_user`

Which is equivalent to:
`price_user = cr_user+100`

Which is equivalent to:
`98.37 = 0.25+100`

Which is equivalent to:
`98.37 = 100.25`

Which is obviously false.

Comment: That's why the code takes into account odd and even cases. In your example, the rhs summation will be equal to 0 as according to sympy it will sum over an empty set is zero if and only if start=end which is the case. Other than that, please see the image if there's other confusion. Also all terms are different so one can't just cancel terms.

Answer (score 0):

What should the second `nsolve` argument be? A: an initial guess for the root.

Giving an initial guess of 0 gives a numerical result which appears to satisfy the equation:

[image]

Comment: NameError: name '_' is not defined ... ? OK ... it's the last calculated value, so _ is ... 0.0480416484284691 .

Answer (score 0):

My attempt ( I haven't yet done anything in sympy, so this is my first attempt to use it) was :

```
lrhs = lhs - rhs  # create a function of x to search where it is zero
print(nsolve(lrhs, x, 0)) # resolve x, use 0 to start with search
```

and I have got:

```
0.0480416484284691
```

Here the code with the outcome checking the equation:

```
lrhs = lhs - rhs
print(nsolve(lrhs, x, 0))               # 0.0480416484284691
print(lrhs.subs(x, 0.0480416484284691)) # 2.55351295663786e-15
```